# Existe algum local correto para carregar bibliotecas nativas do Ruby quando utilizado o Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Em determinada funcionalidade da minha aplicação, preciso utilizar a biblioteca "open-uri", que é nativa do Ruby e não possui uma biblioteca para o Ruby on Rails.

Estou utilizando um `require "open-uri"` onde necessito na aplicação e está funcionando normalmente.

Pergunto: Como não existe uma gem para ser colocada como dependência lá no Gemfile, existe algum local que devo utilizar para carregar essa "dependência", ou posso continuar dando o require onde necessito usar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A forma como você está fazendo está correta. Como `open-uri` é parte da biblioteca padrão do Ruby, você só precisa requerer ela quando for usar.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seria melhor você utilizar um *helper* e depois só chamar ele onde quiser usar a biblioteca padrão Ruby.